# Cakephp when declare relationship in model

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-1.3

when I declare relationship in Model 
Example ::

```
Class User extends AppModel{
var $name = 'User';
**var $hasOne = 'Myprofile';** 

 Class User extends AppModel{
  var $name = 'User';
**var $hasMany = 'Reply';**
```

and I must be declare in

```
Class Myprofile extends AppModel{
var $name ='Myprofile';
var $primaryKey = 'myprofileid';
**var $hasOne = 'User';**


Class Reply extends AppModel{
var $name ='Myprofile';
var $primaryKey = 'myprofileid';
 **var $belongsTo = 'User'**
```

Right or Not

And the other a question
    `user{

          userid

          name

          }

      mywidget{

          mywidgetid

          widgetname

              }

      widgetuse{

           widgetuseid

           mywidget_id

           widget_id`

```
Class Mywidget extends AppModel{
var $name = 'Mywidget';
var $primaryKey = 'mywidgetid';
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Mywidget' => array(
        'className' => 'Mywidget',
        'joinTable' => 'Widgetuse',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'mywidget_id',
        'with' => 'Widgetuse',

right or not
thank you for comment
```

Answer (score 0):

First, stop using "userid" and "profileid" as Primary keys, use "id" instead (as it's by default).

Profile belongsTo User, User hasMany Reply; Reply belongsTo User.

What is the other question?

Comment: Why am I not use the userid replyid.other queston I must be declare
relationship in both model and last I declare HABTMN right or not please answer in my question